# Why I can't compare the extension method's return value to a boolean?

Tags: c#, methods, boolean, streamreader

I try to create an **extension method** that tests whether a streamreader can read data and return a **boolean value**.

My extension method code:

```
 using System.IO;

    namespace ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static class StreamReaderExtension
        {
            public static object isReady(this StreamReader sr)
            {
                if ((sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    return true;
                } else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I would like to use it as shown below:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
if (sr.isReady() == true)
{
//Do something
}
```

But Visual Studio tells me this error message: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

**What did I miss?**

*Sorry for bad english.*

Comment: Why does this function return a `object`?

Comment: Your return type of your method is set to `object`. Dispite you returning true and false, those are not returned as booleans, but objects.

Comment: C# USES CAMEL CASE?

Comment: Your return logic could be simplified to just: `return sr.ReadLine() != null;`

Comment: DONT do this. Your Method hs sideeffects. You discard the first line of the stream you read. I sense disaster!

Comment: I do not have too much experience in programming, so I got a lot of useful information. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is dangerous - it has sideeffects, you discard your full first line of data.

Additionally, your method is absolutely superflous, you do not need it, it is as simple as:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
if (sr.Peek() != -1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Read this [Peek()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems here. First, your method is returning type `object`, which you can't directly compare to type `bool`. As far as the compiler "knows," there's absolutely no reason to believe that a comparison is sensible - for all it knows, you could be doing something like `"bird" == true`, which makes no sense.

Secondly, your method won't do what you think it does even once it compiles:

```
        public static object isReady(this StreamReader sr)
        {
            if ((sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                return true;
            } else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

First, stylistically, if you have a Boolean expression, why not just return that "directly"? This returns `true` exactly when `(sr.ReadLine()) != null` is `true` and `false` exactly when the expression is `false`.

Secondly, as pointed out in the comments, this "consumes" a line without actually storing it anywhere, so you'll actually "lose" data by doing this. (You simply discard the line).

Third, what's the point of this method in the first place? All you're actually doing is a one-line comparison, so there really isn't a reason to have this method at all.

Finally, with this line:

```
if (sr.isReady() == true)
```

There's no reason to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`. You could just write

```
if (sr.isReady())
```

(although, as already pointed out, the method is kind of pointless in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

You have your `isReady()` function defined as returning an object:

```
public static object isReady(this StreamReader sr)
```

Have it return a boolean instead:

```
public static bool isReady(this StreamReader sr)
```

Comment: dont you find his method fishy?

Comment: OP is losing data with their current method and your answer does nothing to address that.

Comment: I do have to agree - it won't do what the OP thinks it does even once they get it to compile, so it's worth pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: The method might be "fishy" and all of the advice on the other answers is good and accurate. But that said, this is the only answer that actually **answers the question** that was asked. +1